# Why does the requests.get with correct header return empty content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a website and copied the Request Headers information from Chrome directly,however, after using the requests.get, the returned content is empty.But the header I printed from requests is correct. Anyone knows the reason for this? Thx!

Mac, Chrome, Python3.7

[General Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck9nf.jpg)[Requests Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oejr.jpg)

```
import requests


headers = {
'Accept': '*/*',

'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',

'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',

'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',

'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',

'Cookie': '_RSG=Ja4TD8hvFh2MGc7wBysunA; _RDG=28458f5367f9b123363c043b75e3f9aa31; _RGUID=2acfe6b2-0d74-4913-ac78-dbc2fa1e6416; _abtest_userid=bce0b01e-fdb6-48c8-9b86-4e1d8ef468df; _ga=GA1.2.937100695.1547968515; Session=SmartLinkCode=U155952&SmartLinkKeyWord=&SmartLinkQuery=&SmartLinkHost=&SmartLinkLanguage=zh; HotelCityID=5split%E5%93%88%E5%B0%94%E6%BB%A8splitHarbinsplit2019-01-25split2019-01-26split0; Mkt_UnionRecord=%5B%7B%22aid%22%3A%224897%22%2C%22timestamp%22%3A1548157938143%7D%5D; ASP.NET_SessionId=w1pq5dvchogxhbnxzmbgbtkk; OID_ForOnlineHotel=1509697509766jepc81550141458933102003; _RF1=123.165.147.203; MKT_Pagesource=PC; HotelDomesticVisitedHotels1=698432=0,0,4.5,3674,/hotel/8000/7899/df84daa197dd4b868868cba4db14f71f.jpg,&448367=0,0,4.3,4455,/fd/hotel/g6/M02/6D/8B/CggYtFc1nAKAEnRYAAdgA-rkEXw300.jpg,&13679014=0,0,4.9,1484,/200g0w000000k4wqrB407.jpg,; __zpspc=9.6.1550232718.1550232718.1%234%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%23; _jzqco=%7C%7C%7C%7C1550232718632%7C1.2024536341.1547968514847.1550141461869.1550232718448.1550141461869.1550232718448.undefined.0.0.13.13; _gid=GA1.2.506035914.1550232719; _bfi=p1%3D102003%26p2%3D102003%26v1%3D18%26v2%3D17; appFloatCnt=8; _bfa=1.1509697509766.jepc8.1.1550141458610.1550232715314.7.19; _bfs=1.2',

'Host': 'hotels.ctrip.com',

'Referer': 'http://hotels.ctrip.com/hotel/698432.html?isFull=F',

'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'

}

url ='http://hotels.ctrip.com/Domestic/tool/AjaxHotelCommentList.aspx?MasterHotelID=698432&hotel=698432&property=0&card=0&cardpos=0&NewOpenCount=0&AutoExpiredCount=0&RecordCount=3663&OpenDate=2015-01-01&currentPage=1&orderBy=2&viewVersion=c&eleven=cb6ab06dc6aff1e215d71d006e6de92d3cb1428213f72763175fe035341c4f61&callback=CASTdHqLYNMOfGFbr&_=1550303542815'

data = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print(data.request.headers)
```

Comment: Have you tried that URL in a browser? It gives a blank page for me.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the URL in a browser and also got a blank page, thus I think it may be related with the Referer or something like this(sorry I just start to learn the crawling).

Comment: And the actual URL is http://hotels.ctrip.com/hotel/698432.html?isFull=F#ctm_ref=hod_sr_lst_dl_n_1_2

Comment: What are you actually trying to scrape from that page?

Answer (score 1):

The request header information that you shared in the image, gives the info that the server responded correctly to the request. Also the actual url that you shared `http://hotels.ctrip.com/Domestic/tool/AjaxHotelCommentList.aspx?MasterHotelID=698432&hotel=698432&property=0&card=0&cardpos=0&NewOpenCount=0&AutoExpiredCount=0&RecordCount=3663&OpenDate=2015-01-01&currentPage=1&orderBy=2&viewVersion=c&eleven=cb6ab06dc6aff1e215d71d006e6de92d3cb1428213f72763175fe035341c4f61&callback=CASTdHqLYNMOfGFbr&_=1550303542815`
 was something different from the one shown in the image. Infact it seems the actual page is indeed calling lot of other urls to form the final page. so there is no guarantee that you will get the response as you see in the browser when you use requests. If the server or the actual implementation at the server end is depending on the browser's javascript engine to execute the javascript and then render the content, you won't be able to get the final html as it looks like in the browser. Would be better to use selenium webdriver in those cases to hit the url and then get the html content. Again if you can share the actual url, can suggest on other ideas

Comment: Yeah many thanks for your reply and actually I have tried the Selenium but just want to practice some other skills:)  Also the actual URL has been attached above.